# Modifying The request object sent by express when testing API request-response

Tags: node.js, rest, express

Im trying to test a simple API request-response using express.
However the requests has to have this fields in the request object:
user.userName and user.password,
this is the code I have thus far:

```
const express = require('express');
const log = require('../../../../logger');
const app = express();
const ClusterNode = require('../cluster-node');

// TODO: don't like these here. Needed to post. Put into global test startup if possible.
// TODO - OMRI: Reaplce this with the global test startup, when created.
const socketio = require('socket.io');
app.io = socketio.listen();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.use('/v2/config/aw/', ClusterNode);
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.user.userName = 'xxxx';
  req.user.password = 'xxxx';
  next();
});

describe('API - ClusterNode', () => {
  test('API - Get Cluster Nodes #1', () => {
    return request(app).get('/v2/config/aw/ClusterNode').then((response) => {
      expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
      expect(response.body.Node.length.toString()).toBe('0');
      expect(response.headers['content-type']).toMatch(/^application\/json/);
    });
  });
});
```

I've tried adding this block of code:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.user.userName = 'xxxx';
  req.user.password = 'xxxx';
  next();
});
```

however it didnt do the job. any idea how this is done?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to have user object in `req.user` use:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 req.user = {
   'userName': 'xxxx',
   'password': 'xxxx'
 };
next();
});
app.use('/v2/config/aw/', ClusterNode);
```

and if you want it to be in your `req.body` use:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 req.body.user = {
   'userName': 'xxxx',
   'password': 'xxxx'
 };
next();
});
app.use('/v2/config/aw/', ClusterNode);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your middleware function to set userName and password is declared after your route handler, so my guess is that it's not called. Move it before you declare your route e.g

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.user = {
    'userName': 'xxxx',
    'password': 'xxxx'
  };
  next();
});
app.use('/v2/config/aw/', ClusterNode);
```

Comment: after following the code you posted,Im getting response.code(500), and when I debug the call Im not getting routerd to method handeling that request.

Comment: i am not getting from where you are passing user object in req. if you are using body parser that means you should be passing it in req.body. @OmriShneor

Comment: as Dhaval points out I can't see where you are actually create req.user to begin with so I've changed my code to create it